# WPF XAML Binding List and Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am teaching myself how to bind classes to XAML objects.  I can't find anything on data within lists.  Either that or I don't know the terminology very well.  I want to make a combobox that is tied to the list, displaying the name of each Item in the Items list.  How would I bind this to the combobox?

```
class Section
{
    List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
}

class Item
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Xiaoy is right, but you should also change your list to and ObservableCollection if you want that the changes in the collection (adding and removing items for instance) are replicated in the combobox

Comment: Thanks! I'll look up how to use those!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This,

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Make your Items collection as a property.

```
 public List<Item> Items { get; set;}
```

`Section` Class should be `public` and make it as your `DataContext`

Comment: The issue was making section get; set;.  Turned it back to = new and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `Section` is the current DataContext :

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```